# handle an event and attach a command in the same time

Tags: wpf, events, command

I have got a question about event and bound command.

What happens if I bound a command to my button and also handle the click event in my code behind ?

I mean, I have already tried and everything is ok but I was wondering whether this affects the efficiency or something else ?
Is it a good practice ?

In my case the code behind is just to close a window after it has executed a command.

thank you everybody

Comment: i would not call this a good practice. i am not even sure whether the behaviour is deterministic, i mean it is undefined whether the event is fired after or before the command.

Comment: I don't know that's why I was asking. But in my case, it works every time.

Comment: That seems a bit strange, if you need both types of behaviour, wouldn't it be better to methodise the commands code and then call it from the buttons click handler?

Comment: But the command is processing in a view model who has no idea about my window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely not a best practice, since they are two different ways of achieving the same outcome. What you may want to do investigate as a solution, is passing a callback as the parameter (or part of the parameter object) of your command and have the command call the method/callback.

If you must, you can also specify, with a flag, whether the callback should be called before of after the command's code block completes.

Answer (score 0):

It's deterministic, but I only think it's "good practice" if:

- Your command is providing some business logic **AND**
- The click event is being handled to do something purely view-related, such as begin a storyboard.

You could always trigger the view response from the viewmodel instead if you wanted (in my example you could use a datastatebehavior)